# Capture Excel Pivot Table Refresh event

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

Is there an event corresponding to the data refresh of a pivot table?
I have found the

```
    worksheet_pivottableupdate
```

event but this seems to be called everytime I change filters or manipulate the pivottable (which is quite frequently with my macros). What I need is just to capture when the underlying data is updated. Any way to do this?

Comment: what about using the `worksheet_change` event of the sheet where the source data is located?

Comment: Have you got an example of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to tackle this is to use the `pivottableupdate` event, and combine it with checking that the following pivot-table property has changed.

```
PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshDate
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff834610(v=office.14).aspx for more information on the RefreshDate property.