# macro to change multiple slicer values

Tags: excel, slicers, vba

I am at a loss after some searching.
 I have two pivot tables driven from two different data source/caches. source 1 is a table with departments' total charged amounts, source 2 has the same departments with the total denied dollar amounts. I am pulling the data from both of these into pivot tables so that I can manipulate the department (among other things) to calculate percentages.

My original thought was to set a "Department" slicer for each table, and have a macro assigned to one of the slicers to change the second one so that both pivot tables filter the department. I was also thinking of possibly using one slicer, and assigning it a macro to simply filter the department on the second pivot.

both of these tables will be hidden  with the exception of one of the slicers and will have the calculated data from each table pulled to the top of the sheet for easy viewing.

both sheets/data sources are derived from separate reports with completely different data & headers.

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I am having a difficult time understanding what you want. Do you have some sample data, current layout and a mock-up of the desired output / layout? Also, your tags currently indicate that you are looking for a VBA solution. So, could you please include the VBA code you have written thus far?

Comment: I want whatever slicer #1's value is to automatically change slicer #2's value to the same.

Comment: Oh, in this case your post seems to be simply a duplicate of the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056831/capture-excel-pivot-table-refresh-event Please verify. If that's the case then you might as well remove your post. I sure hope the referenced post and answer solve your problem.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that is in no way close.

Comment: If doing away with the original slicer inquiry and focusing purely on the pivottable which seems the direction `pivottableupdate` and .`DateRefresh` was taking me, the question would remain how do I express     

    `PivotTable2.PivotFields ("Department").value = PivotTable1.PivotFields("Department").value` ?

Comment: and I mean of course without using 

    `pivotitems ("item1").visible = true
     pivotitems ("item2").visible = false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came across something useful on [contextures](http://www.contextures.com/excelslicersupdatevba.html)

It works exactly how I want it to, I simply linked the slicer connected to 4 other pivot tables with a separate cache than my "main" slicer/table and hid the linked slicer. When I select and option from the main slicer, it updates the hidden slicer thus filtering all the other pivot tables.