# VBA to connect slicers (looking for improvements to code)

Tags: excel, pivot-table, slicers, vba

I finally found a code that will connect slicers with different caches on pivot table update. Basically when the value of slicer1 changes, it will change slicer2 to match slicer1 thus updating any pivot table connected to the second slicer.

I've added `.Application.ScreenUpdating` and `.Application.EnableEvents` in an attempt to speed up the macro but it's still laggy and causes Excel to become unresponsive.

Is there a more direct way of coding this or are there any potentially volatile lines in here causing Excel to fry it's brain?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate _
    (ByVal Target As PivotTable)
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim scShort As SlicerCache
Dim scLong As SlicerCache
Dim siShort As SlicerItem
Dim siLong As SlicerItem

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo errHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set scShort = wb.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Department")
Set scLong = wb.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Department2")

scLong.ClearManualFilter

For Each siLong In scLong.VisibleSlicerItems
    Set siLong = scLong.SlicerItems(siLong.Name)
    Set siShort = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set siShort = scShort.SlicerItems(siLong.Name)
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    If Not siShort Is Nothing Then
        If siShort.Selected = True Then
            siLong.Selected = True
        ElseIf siShort.Selected = False Then
            siLong.Selected = False
        End If
    Else
        siLong.Selected = False
    End If
Next siLong

exitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not update pivot table"
    Resume exitHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

original code found on [Contextures](http://www.contextures.com/excelslicersupdatevba.html)

Thanks for any advice as always.

[link to original inquiry:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39376238/macro-to-change-multiple-slicer-values/39599114#39599114)

Comment: How many slicer items do you loop through?

Comment: It's probably just going to be slow. Monkeying with sliceritems in a slicercache causes filtering on it's connected pivotcache, which takes processing. So everytime it flips a `sliceritem.selected` to `true` or `false` the pivotcache gets filtered for the connected pivot table and excel crawls. I guess.. theoretically you could empty the connected pivot's pivotcache (temporarily move the data but not the headers and refresh), then run this code to filter the nothing by toggling the `sliceritems.Selected` property and then tossing the data back in and refreshing the pivottable all at once...?

Comment: @Kyle          Alot and probably more to come.

I'm wondering if it would be a better/quicker solution to set the value/selection of "slicer2" to match that of a hidden cell?
e.g. have A1 = the filtered value of the main pivot table and then set "slicer2" selection to equal that of cell A1?
I'm unsure how to decipher this though, have not turned up any functional coding so far.

Comment: How many items in each slicer will be selected? Just 1? Or will you want users to be able to make multiple selections?

Comment: And when you say 'a lot and probably more to come' can you be more specific? How many PivotTables do you need to sync up? How many PivotItems are in each of them?

Comment: I have my one "main" pivot table and chart from one cache, then 4 additional pivots from another cache. I want only one item to be selected for each of the two desired slicers. One of the slicers will have 150+ items, the other will just be months. I did try some work with syncing the pivots up rather than the slicer but this will not work for me I don't think, as I do not have a matching field for what I am filtering with the slicer. For example the additional pivots have only the fields, "users" w/ count of user to display the top 5....

Comment: ...users for a given criteria. I do not have a field corresponding to the slicer with 150+ items or a "date of" field, and I do not want to add them. However when I select a department from the slicer (the slicer with 150+ items) or a month from the second slicer, it will filter the synced tables accordingly. I was unable to achieve this with the pivots directly because there is a missing pagefield. It's also note worthy that I am incredibly inexperienced with VBA and have just recently began to dabble so I'm unsure if using the slave pivots would be a workaround for that.

Comment: My *Connect with slicers, sync Slaves with VBA* approach will work even though your displayed pivots don't have the 'Department' field in them. See new screenshot in my answer below. Try it out, and holler if you get stuck. Otherwise, you're going to be stuck with the slow iteration-based approach that you have.

Comment: Got it to work in a test file. This is awesome thank you!. I am struggling however, to figure out how to get this to work with a second slicer field. I want the user to only be able to select one item in the slicer but I would like an additional one for dates. I attempted to create a second set of slaves and repeat the code but get hit with a duplicate `sField` error. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the user to select just one item at a time, you can do this very quickly by using the following trick that leverages off a quirk to do with PageFields. Here's an example where I sync three different PivotTables that are on different caches.

1. Set up a slave PivotTable for each of the master PivotTables
   somewhere out of sight, and put the field of interest in each of
   them as a PageField, like this:

   [image]
2. Make sure the 'Select Multiple Items' checkbox is *deselected* for each of those slave PivotTables:
   [image]
3. Add a Slicer to each of those Slaves. Again, these will be somewhere out of sight:
   [image]
4. Connect each of those Slicers up to the actual PivotTables you had to begin with. (i.e. connect each hidden Slicer to it's visible counterpart PivotTable using the Report Connections box.
   [image]

Now this is where the clever hack comes in: We move the Slicer that is connected to the *PivotTable1 Slave* PivotTable into the main sheet so the user can click on it. When they select an item using it, it generates a PivotTable_Update event for that *PivotTable1 Slave* PivotTable, which we keep an eye out for. And then we set the .PageField of those other slave PivotTables to match the .PageField of the *PivotTable1 Slave* PivotTable. And then more magic happens: that single selection in those slave PageFields gets replicated in the master PivotTables thanks to those hidden Slicers we set up earlier. No VBA neccessary. No slow iteration necessary. Just lightning fast syncing.

Here's how the entire setup looks:
[image]

...and this will work even if the field you want to filter on isn't visible in any of your pivots:
[image]

Here's the code that achieves this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim sCurrentPage As String
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim vArray As Variant

'########################
'# Change these to suit #
'########################

Const sField As String = "Name"
vArray = Array("PivotTable2 Slave", "PivotTable3 Slave")


If Target.Name = "PivotTable1 Slave" Then
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Find out what item they just selected
    Set pf = Target.PivotFields(sField)
    With pf
        If .EnableMultiplePageItems Then
            .ClearAllFilters
            .EnableMultiplePageItems = False
            sCurrentPage = "(All)"
        Else:
            sCurrentPage = .CurrentPage
        End If
    End With

    'Change the other slave pivots to match. Slicers will pass on those settings
    For Each vItem In vArray
        Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(vItem)
        Set pf = pt.PivotFields(sField)
        With pf
            If .CurrentPage <> sCurrentPage Then
                .ClearAllFilters
                .CurrentPage = sCurrentPage
            End If
        End With
    Next vItem

errhandler:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

There's a bit of code in there to ensure that the user can't select more than one item in the slicer at a time.

**But what if you want the User to be able to select *multiple* items?**

If you want the user to be able to select multiple items, things become way, way more complicated.  For starters, you need to set each PivotTable's ManualUpdate property to TRUE so that they don't refresh ater each and every PivotItems changes. And even then, it can take minutes to sync just one PivotTable if it has say 20,000 items in it. I've got a good post on this at the following link that I'd recommend you read, that shows just how long it takes to perform different actions when it comes to iterate through a large number of PivotItems:
http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/

Even then, you have a lot of other challenges to overcome depending on what you're doing. Slicers seem to really slow things down, for starters. Read my post at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2015/11/17/filtering-pivottables-with-vba-deselect-slicers-first/ for more on this.

I'm in the final stages of launching a commercial addin that does a lot of this stuff lightning fast, but launch is at least a month away.

Comment: Hey thanks a ton for the reply, I added an additional reply to your comments above the answer. I'm unsure if this will work for me as you'll read above. Another approach I was trying to figure out was if I could send selected item of slicer 1 to a cell and use that value to drive the selection of  the slicer for the tables on the second cache.  thanks a ton.

Comment: Yes, you can send the selected item of Slicer1 to a cell, but then you are still faced with the issue of syncing Slicer2 to that one item. Which will require you to iterate though the SlicerItems of Slicer2 (or one of the PivotTables it connects to) and which brings you right back to your initial issue. Read this link, because it explains the inherent problems involved in that:
http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/

Comment: If you set .ManualUpdate to true in all the pivots connected to Slicer2 while you do that then things should get faster. But that is still a heck of a lot more complicated than my suggested approach above of using Slave pivots to both 'harvest' the click on Slicer1 and then efficiently sync that single selection on to the other Pivots via Slicer2

Comment: I cannot figure out how this could be tweaked to allow syncing of two different slicer categories. Tried second set of slave tables, second page field, hmm.

Comment: Awill...what are the two different slicer category names? You basically need to duplicate everything between my comment at the top and the errhandler at the bottom, and then change the following bits to reflect the name of the second slicer and pivots:
 Const sField As String = "Name"
vArray = Array("PivotTable2 Slave", "PivotTable3 Slave")
If Target.Name = "PivotTable1 Slave" Then...

Comment: Hi, that was my original attempt, however I was getting flagged for a duplicate declaration in scope with the sField As String = all highlighted when I chose debug.

Comment: sorry missed this; the first slicer category is department. I have that successfully updating all my tables. It's giving me overall/total metrics for the department selected but I also want to be able to break it down by date with a month slicer.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. Change *Const sField As String = "SomeFieldName"* to *sField = "SomeFieldName"* and also add *DIM sField as String* to the declarations at the top.

Comment: That said, there may be a better way to handle syncing of the dates. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105890/filtering-multiple-pivot-tables-based-on-drop-down-selections-using-vba/39111413#39111413 Also, what version of Excel are you doing? It strikes me that if you have 2013 or later you should consider using the DataModel to link the underlying source tables, so that everything can then appear in the same PivotCache.

Comment: Tossed my outcome up top since it was much too long.

Comment: Would you be opposed to me emailing you my example instead of dragging out the comments? I'm also struggling with getting one of my pivots with combined data from two other pivots to update automatically. It works perfectly fine when manually updating it, but when I attempt to add code to the worksheet it bugs out, hope I didn't just break any posting rules by commenting on a second roadblock I'm running into with this sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what I'm doing incorrect. I posted my code below, I'm not hitting any errors, it's simply just not updating any of the other slicers/fields. Upon first test, the Department slicer updated all the tables once, but then would not clear the filter or allow another selection, as far as the Month slicer, I haven't gotten it to work at all. Do I perhaps need to duplicate each item so that it's separately identifiable? As in `Dim sCurrentPage As String` and `Dim sCurrentPage2 As String`. Thank you so much for your continued assistance with this, I've never wanted the weekend to come so badly while working on a spreadsheet before.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim sCurrentPage As String
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim vArray As Variant
Dim sField As String

'########################
'# Change these to suit #
'########################

sField = "Department"
vArray = Array("PivotTable2 Slave", "PivotTable3 Slave")


If Target.Name = "PivotTable1 Slave" Then
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Find out what item they just selected
    Set pf = Target.PivotFields(sField)
    With pf
        If .EnableMultiplePageItems Then
            .ClearAllFilters
            .EnableMultiplePageItems = False
            sCurrentPage = "(All)"
        Else:
            sCurrentPage = .CurrentPage
        End If
    End With

    'Change the other slave pivots to match. Slicers will pass on those settings
    For Each vItem In vArray
        Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(vItem)
        Set pf = pt.PivotFields(sField)
        With pf
            If .CurrentPage <> sCurrentPage Then
                .ClearAllFilters
                .CurrentPage = sCurrentPage
            End If
        End With
    Next vItem

'########################

sField = "Month"
vArray = Array("PivotTable2 Slave2", "PivotTable3 Slave2")


If Target.Name = "PivotTable1 Slave2" Then
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Find out what item they just selected
    Set pf = Target.PivotFields(sField)
    With pf
        If .EnableMultiplePageItems Then
            .ClearAllFilters
            .EnableMultiplePageItems = False
            sCurrentPage = "(All)"
        Else:
            sCurrentPage = .CurrentPage
        End If
    End With

    'Change the other slave pivots to match. Slicers will pass on those settings
    For Each vItem In vArray
        Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(vItem)
        Set pf = pt.PivotFields(sField)
        With pf
            If .CurrentPage <> sCurrentPage Then
                .ClearAllFilters
                .CurrentPage = sCurrentPage
            End If
        End With
    Next vItem

errhandler:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Awill - flick your spreadsheet to me at weir.jeff@gmail.com and I'll take a look, and then post back here.

Comment: Given this answer has addressed your original question, how 'bout you mark it as Accepted.