# Remove all from Pivot filter in VBA

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I am trying to remove every country in the "countryName" filed list within a pivot table.

however I get a runtime error 1004, which I believe is down to trying to eliminate the "All" selection. My code is below:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("countryName")
.ClearAllFilters
    .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    .PivotItems("All").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("GREAT-BRITAIN").Visible = False
End With
```

Where "countyName" is the field 
GREAT-BRITAIN is the only country I want displayed

I could do this manually but every time I import new data the country list could differ hence I want to remove "all" then just leaving "GREAT-BRITAIN"

Many thanks to anyone who can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, a couple of alternatives to VBA, in case you haven't considered them.  You can use a Slicer to do this with the exact same outcome. Or if you want the user to choose a country from a dropdown, you can use the approach I outline at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/08/16/sync-pivots-from-dropdown/

I take it from the line .EnableMultiplePageItems = True in your code that you are dealing with a PageField? If so, you want to keep .EnableMultiplePageItems set to false, and just change the PageField property.

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("countryName")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .CurrentPage = "GREAT-BRITAIN"
End With
```

Otherwise you will have to iterate through every item (other than GREAT-BRITAIN) in your PivotTable and set the .visible status to false, which is very slow. (See my post at the following link, as it discusses how to overcome bottlenecks when filtering Pivots with VBA:
http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/)

If your field is NOT a PageField, then you can still do this quickly by setting up a 'Master' PivotTable somewhere out of sight, putting the field of interest in the master as a PageField, connecting the Master PivotTable to PivotTable1 ('Slave')  with a Slicer, and using the code snippet above on the hidden Master to set the PageField instantly on one item. The Slicer then syncs the Master with the Slave instantly. I use this approach at 
[VBA to connect slicers (looking for improvements to code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599449/vba-to-connect-slicers-looking-for-improvements-to-code)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I spend a LOT of time coding PivotTables, so if you have any other requirements just holler. Are you going to use code, or slicers to do this? If code, is there any chance that you or a user might select the 'Select Multiple Items' checkbox? Because that will cause the code to error.

Comment: Ah, I see from a second read of your initial post that you are the user here.

Comment: Note that if your PivotTable is filtered on GB, then any time you add new data, it should STILL be filtered on GB, unless for some reason GB wasn't in the data. So I'm not entirely sure why you need to refilter the data. Unless I'm missing something. Which happens a lot. :-)

Comment: Hi,

I am constructing the VBA code for pivot tables for someone that doesn't use excel much.

I have a list of sales people in excel spreadsheet "Names"

For example:

    John
    Chris
    Amber
    Catherine

In the same code I want to be able to use this list so the VBA filters automatically in the pivot table within an xlRowField (PivotFields("SalespersonName")),  (row field 1).

Comment: As before the list of names can change all the time so I want to be able to remove the "all" bit and just add the names above. I tried changing the code you gave above but this obviously doesnt work as its for xlPageField.  If you understand what I mean, do you have any ideas on how I could proceed? So Many thanks!

Comment: So is the PivotTable only being  filtered on one name at a time? Or all of them?

Comment: all of them each time, out of a list of hundreds, which could change each day (new names added)

Comment: Okay, in that case you should use the code I posted above: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/

Comment: You can also use the DataModel to do this kind of thing, with no code necessary. What version of Excel do you have? You can usually see this if you click File and then Account. For instance, I have Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus. What does yours say?

Comment: Just for the sake of future humanity. The 1004 error you get is because pivot tables don't allow you to uncheck all items in a pivot field, there must be at least one.