# Combining Excel Slicers and Multiple Pivot Table with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, slicers

I'm trying to combine a Excel Pivot Table Slicer to control multiple pivot tables form different data tables.

I've found a function do detect and record the Slicer's active selection:

```
Public Function SlicerSelections(Slicer_Name As String)
FblSlicerSelections = ""

Dim i As Integer

With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches(Slicer_Name)
    For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
        If .SlicerItems(i).Selected Then
            SlicerSelections = SlicerSelections & " " & .SlicerItems(i).Value
    End If
    Next i
End With
End Function
```

Now I want to use the results of these function to alter the pivot fields of others pivot tables.

All the pivot tables shares a number of common fields, like primaries keys.
I've already tried to create a single query to combine all the data into a single table, so I could use Slicers to navigate trough the data in different pivot tables, but, as the unique queries has different number of registers for  a single set of primary keys, the end result was messy.

How can I use the results of SlicerSelections function to alter the filter parameters (pivot fields) of a Pivot Table and refresh it, so I can use the first pivot table slicer and a macro to command all the pivot tables within a spreadsheet?

Thank you all.

Well, things didn't go as smooth as I imagine.
The procedure works very well with a static data base. I mean, of I don't change the original data sets.
But the data sets have to change, because the data tables will be fulfilled by a query.
First error that apear was the Run Time Error 5.
So I've researched a little bit and understood that the pivotcaches should be reseted in order to run the procedure multiple times.
I've found a code to do that, but now I'm facing the following error: Run time error 1004 -  Application Defined or Objected Defined error.

Here is the codes:

```
Sub Atualiza_Din()
'Dim pvtf As PivotField
Call PivotCacheReset

' Definição das variáveis de controle
Set pvtf_Dias_cen = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TDDias").PivotFields("Número")
Set pvtf_Dias_per = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TDDias").PivotFields("PER_Nome")
Set pvtf_Dias_ref = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TDDias").PivotFields("REF_Nome")
Set pvtf_Dias_tpu = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TDDias").PivotFields("TPU_Nome")
Set pvtf_Dias_upr = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TDDias").PivotFields("UPR_Nome")

Set pvtf_Prod_cen = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TDProd").PivotFields("Número")
Set pvtf_Prod_per = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TDProd").PivotFields("PER_Nome")
Set pvtf_Prod_ref = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TDProd").PivotFields("REF_Nome")
Set pvtf_Prod_tpu = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TDProd").PivotFields("TPU_Nome")
Set pvtf_Prod_upr = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TDProd").PivotFields("UPR_Nome")

cen = SlicerSelections("SegmentaçãodeDados_Número1") 'Identifica o cenário selecionado
per = SlicerSelections("SegmentaçãodeDados_PER_Nome1") 'Identifica o período selecionado
ref = SlicerSelections("SegmentaçãodeDados_REF_Nome1") 'Identifica a refinaria selecionada
tpu = SlicerSelections("SegmentaçãodeDados_TPU_Nome1") 'Identifica o processo selecionado
upr = SlicerSelections("SegmentaçãodeDados_UPR_Nome1") 'Identifica a unidade selecionada
'MsgBox (ref)

pvtf_Dias_cen.CurrentPage = cen
pvtf_Dias_per.CurrentPage = per
pvtf_Dias_ref.CurrentPage = ref
pvtf_Dias_tpu.CurrentPage = tpu
pvtf_Dias_upr.CurrentPage = upr

pvtf_Prod_cen.CurrentPage = cen
pvtf_Prod_per.CurrentPage = per
pvtf_Prod_ref.CurrentPage = ref
pvtf_Prod_tpu.CurrentPage = tpu
pvtf_Prod_upr.CurrentPage = upr

End Sub
```

And here is the pivot cache reset:

```
Sub PivotCacheReset()
' When a data set is pivoted and then some of the underlying data is
'  removed, even after a refresh old removed values can still remain in the
'  pivot filter.  This macro changes the properties of all pivot tables in
'  the active workbook, to prevent missing items from appearing, or clear
'  items that have appeared. It also resets all pivot table caches in the
'  active workbook.

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim iWs As Worksheet
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim iProtectState As Boolean

    ' Loop through each worksheet.
    For Each iWs In wb.Worksheets

        ' If the worksheet is protected, unprotect it. Remember
        '  it was protected so that it can be re-protected later.
        iProtectState = False                    ' Reset variable that remembers if each sheet is protected.
        If iWs.ProtectContents = True Then
            ' Worksheet is protected.
            iWs.Unprotect                        ' Unprotect the worksheet.
            iProtectState = True                 ' Remember that this worksheet was protected.
        End If

        ' Loop through each pivot table in the sheet.
        For Each pvt In iWs.PivotTables
            pvt.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone ' Don't allow missing items in the pivot table filters.
            pvt.PivotCache.Refresh               ' Reset the pivot table cache including any missing items.
        Next pvt

        ' If the worksheet was originally protected, re-protect it.
        If iProtectState = True Then iWs.Protect

    Next iWs

End Sub
```

Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39604425/2507160 which should get you to where you need to go.

Comment: I checked your proposal of solution, but I have some questions:
- should the slave pivot tables be linked to the original data sets or to the pivot tables itself?
- I have to create slicers for each variable that I want to control? I mean, I have 5 control variables, so I have to have 5 slicers for each one of slave pivot tables?
Thanks very much

Comment: So, working a little bit more and analyzing the SlicerSelections function I noticed that the function inserted a space (" ") in the selected slicer value. I've altered the function and combine with a previous sub and I've managed to do what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome. Please mark the other post as helpful if it solves your issue.