# Excel slicer connections won't display all pivot tables

Tags: excel-2010, slicers

I am using power query to get my tables from an external workbook. When I create a slicer for one of my pivot tables the other pivot tables don't show up in the pivottable connection. I want to have one slicer for multiple pivot tables and I am not sure why the pivot tables isn't showing up. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: As teylyn points out, PivotTables need to be on the same PivotCache in order to do this out of the box. That said, you can also use VBA in need to do this. Are you wanting to sync the PivotTables on just one item? Or multiple items?

Comment: I want to force the user to only be able to select one item in the pivot table and if they click that i want to take effect on multiple pivot tables.

Comment: I don't have power pivot so VBA would be my only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slicer can only connect to a pivot table that uses the same pivot cache. Chances are that if you don't see the other pivot tables in the slicer connection, they are using a different pivot cache.

If you use Power Query to get the data, make sure that you add the query to the workbook data model. Pivot tables that are created from the data model will share the same pivot cache.

Comment: So I would add my query from my external table to the data model?

Comment: Yes. With Excel 2010 you need to activate Power Pivot, so you can add data to the data model. You can add queries to different data sources to the data model and then create pivot tables.

Comment: I am using power query is that ok

Comment: Power Query is a query tool. In order to use the data model in XL 2010 you need Power Pivot. In Power Pivot you can create relationships between tables. If you have two different tables that you want to filter with one slicer, there must be a relationship between the two tables. That can only be created in the data model.

Answer (score 0):

Given you don't have PowerPivot installed (or don't have the DataModel that is built in to Excel 2013 or later) then you've got two options:

1. Join both data sources in PowerQuery on a common field, so that you
   bring in just one Table. Then everything will be on the same
   PivotCache (allowing Slicers) if not PivotTable.
2. Use one VBA routine to limit slicer selection to one item only, and another routine to sync slicers across different PivotCaches.

If you elect for the latter, then [Jerry Sullivan's code from this link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/675168-limiting-slicer-multiple-selection-2.html#post4595304) will limit users to selecting just one item in a Slicer, and my code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39604425/2507160 will then show you how to sync this Slicer to other Slicers on different PivotCaches, in order to keep all Pivots showing the same thing.